# Why Am I Getting a NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby, function, methods

```
class UnitCircle
    def prompt
        puts "Enter a number: "
        @number = gets
        @number = @number.to_i
        puts "Enter a trigonometric equation to perform on that number: "
        @eqn = gets
    end
end
uc = UnitCircle.new
uc.prompt
num = Math.send(uc.instance_eval {@eqn}, uc.instance_eval {@number})
```

When I try to run it with say,

```
@number = 30
@eqn = sin
```

I get a no method error, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class UnitCircle
    def prompt
        puts "Enter a number: "
        @number = gets.chomp
        @number = @number.to_i
        puts "Enter a trigonometric equation to perform on that number: "
        @eqn = gets.chomp
    end
end
```

`gets` method will include the new line symbol "\n". So you have to `chomp` it.
If you do not chomp, you will end up calling method "sin\n" instead of "sin"